# But where is my scale pgfkeys?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I'd like to access to the `/tilz/scale`, the pgfkeysvalueof returns an empty string.

Is there a `.store` macro dedicated to ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

\node {*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tilz/scale}*} ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think `scale` might be a style for `x scale` and `y scale` (I never remember if with spaces or not). Maybe try to get the values of one of those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scale is not stored in the form you expect: it's passed directly to the `pgf` base layer. If you try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/scale/.show code}
```

you get

```
> \pgfkeysshower=\long macro:
#1\pgfeov ->\tikz@addtransform {\pgftransformscale {#1}}.
\pgfkeys@code ...keysshower }\show \pgfkeysshower
```

*i.e.* there is a TikZ wrapper passing to `\pgftransformscale`. The latter stores the data in a matrix: one can recover it using `\pgfgettransformentries` or `\pgfgettransform` (the latter has everything in one macro):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/scale = 2}
\pgfgettransformentries\aa\ab\ba\bb\xhsift\yshift
\show\aa 
\show\ab
\show\ba
\show\bb
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```